# SSL DV certificate not working uniformly across browsers, ISP and OS

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, security-certificate

I purchased SSL certificate through Namecheap.

I am using Windows 11 OS, with BSNL Internet Service Operator(wifi) with Firefox v16, Microsoft Edge, Chrome v106 as browsers and iPad OS version 16 and iPhone OS version 16 with the same BSNL Internet Service Operator(wifi). Having Safari (latest), Firefox (latest), Chrome (latest) browsers in iOS.

Expected Behavior:

It is World Wide Web(internet) and hence the SSL certificate should work fine with all the browsers, irrespective of devices or major browsers (at least major browsers in recent releases). I cleared DNS cache in Desktop, reset network settings in iOS and cleared internet cache/history.

Actual Behavior:

It was working fine with Microsoft Edge browser in Desktop, but it was not with other browsers. Later the hosting provider resolved the issue by fixing something in .htaccess file.

I referred in internet and found this link

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/901/2223/my-ssl-is-installed-why-do-i-get-the-warning-not-secure-in-browsers/

which matches their solution. I am using WordPress v5.7, PHP v7.x and shared web hosting in Linux Apache. Previously, the website was working in older firefox versions, without https certificate. Now, it is not opening at all. A secure connection to the website cannot be established error is throwing up. How to make it work in older web browsers uniformly?

Comment: Please update your question so all of the details are in it.

Comment: You know if you check youtube.com on sslchecker it also says that root1 is missing? Older browsers may not have anything close to the current list of trusted domain authorities that is currently in use on the internet. Firefox did not offer the ability to update its internal list until v49 -- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/setting-certificate-authorities-firefox

Comment: Are you getting a “This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store” in your older browser?

Comment: It cannot establish secure connection with the server; the data might be compromised ; a message like that